# Allow a user to run a single command as root over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a user account that is not designed for logging in interactively, but want to allow it to run a single command (as root). Is there a better way to accomplish this (without granting more rights than I intend to) than I have currently:

- Changing their shell to rbash, with sudo as the only executable in
  their path, as they need a valid shell in order to run any commands.
- Adding their account to sudoers with "ALL=(root:root)
  NOPASSWD: /sbin/executable"
- Adding an authorized_keys entry for the
  account with no-{X11,port}-forwarding,no-pty,command="sudo executable"

Context: I am trying to grant a non-*nix savvy manager the ability to fix any print server troubles while I am away. Obviously first port of call is the CUPS web interface and physically walking over and inspecting the printer (which he can and does do now), but I can't expect him to ssh in and restart the appropriate services when that fails (and do not trust him with unrestricted sudo access anyway). Currently I am just giving him access to run /sbin/reboot, and I will change that to a script that restarts cups/samba/etc. instead when I get a chance.

Comment: Is there any issue with the approaches you have listed? It seems like a perfectly reasonable way to me.

Comment: I agree with terdon - except that if possible, I'd also limit the IP addresses from which the key can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid any other possible interraction with the server, one  way is to create a dedicated account with your command as connection shell.
For instance user "reboot" with uid 0 and /sbin/reboot as connection shell.

The shell can be a script menu, authorizing to choose between options; that way you can use sudo and avoid the UID 0 for the account

```
1) Purge the print jobs
2) Restart cups
3) Reboot 
4) Quit
Enter your choice:
```

[Menus scripting here](http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/shell_programming_and_simple_menus_part_1.htm)
[Much simpler example using bash select function on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346161/menu-driven-shell-script-bash)

Better authenticate with personal ssh keys, that way you will know who is rebooting the server.

Comment: A menu like that would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @GarethWebb I added a link that points to a very good example of use of the bash "select" function.

Comment: To create a nice menu, I would recommend to use: whiptail (https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/11/24/10-advanced-linux-command-line-tools/#attachment_424), more examples: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it, its to run a web-server-script* executed by root and which executes only the commands you need (like the menu proposed by Emmanuel). 
Then, you can protect it using a password, or a firewall to restrict who can access to it.

*web-server-script: it can be [a small perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425220/perl-http-server) (using HTTP::Daemon), a [small java webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572127/tiniest-java-web-server), or anything else, running in a non common port (like higher than 1000).